# Can a prepaid Amex be legally allowed to expire in Canada?

Tags: credit-card, canada, law

While moving, I recently found an old prepaid Amex card that I had originally selected from my then-employer's "recognition" benefits program. The card expired in 2013, but my understanding is that in Canada it is not legal for the funds on a prepaid card be allowed to expire [see [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/rights-responsibilities/rights-prepaid-products.html), which is not conclusive]. However, I have not found any success towards getting a new card re-issued by Amex.

Not only has the card itself been expired for over 10 years, but the benefits program that issued it is defunct, and the reward card program ("Achievers") is now run by Mastercard, not Amex. I don't know who might technically "own" this debt, but I certainly haven't gotten anyone to admit that they do.

**Am I correct in saying that legally, I should be able to get these funds?** And, perhaps more critically, how might I be able to convince someone to follow through on that requirement?

Is there perhaps a governmental ombudsman-type organization I could reach out to? It almost feels like a 'lost funds' situation...

Comment: What happens when you call the number on the back of the card and provide the card number?

Comment: @bobson The number on the back of the card has been deprecated, as the sub-group of Amex that used to run the program, no longer does. It's been so long, that whatever extended period they had originally intended to duplicate services for those with the old cards, has now expired.

Comment: Did you receive an email or any paperwork along with the card? Long time ago, so I can understand that you might not still have it. This sounds like an employee reward program that employers use, and I would assume that falls under the Promotional Prepaid Card designation noted on the website you linked to. Typically those cards start charging a monthly fee after 12 months of no activity until the funds are gone. The expiration date on the physical card is usually more for merchant usage (because CC forms on eCommerce pages require a date) and not the same date as funds expiration.

Comment: @BobbyScon I'm sure I received both paperwork and an email at the start, but that's a few moves + employers ago! To be honest, I don't even know how I would be able to validate myself or the card at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This may need to be further refined to which province you reside in (or did at the time of receiving the pre-paid card). The answer may be universal to Canada, but the verbiage for different provinces leaves it a bit open-ended from my non-legal-professional viewpoint.

Take these website articles for example:

Ontario: https://www.ontario.ca/page/buying-or-using-gift-cards

- Prepaid cards are explicitly excluded from gift card rules and can therefore expire
- You can contact [Consumer Protection](https://www.ontario.ca/page/filing-consumer-complaint) and inquire there.

Alberta: https://www.alberta.ca/information-about-gift-cards

- The term prepaid isn't used, but this might fall under "gift cards with a direct agreement between the consumer and the financial institution"
- Recommended approach might be to contact Service Alberta and Red Tape Reduction’s Consumer Contact Centre

My takeaway is that you're most likely out of luck and the card will be considered invalid either because it falls into a category excluded by the gift card rules or because the program under Amex is defunct.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't considered provincial legislation on this, I'll dig deeper with that in mind!